# Reference request for bounded cohomology

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I want to read Gromov's IHES paper *Volume and bounded cohomolgy*. I have a decent background in algebraic topology at the level of Hatcher. What other background is required to understand the landmark paper ?

Comment: Start reading [it](http://www.ihes.fr/~gromov/PDF/4[35].pdf) and you'll see when you need some background you don't have yet. (From what I see, Riemannian geometry is of help, as it is the lead motivations and examples.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you read two of the early papers which gave the first interesting examples of infinite dimensional bounded cohomology. In the first paper Brooks computes 2-D bounded cohomology of free groups, and in the second paper Brooks and Series compute 2-D bounded cohomology of surface groups.

1. Brooks, Robert. "Some remarks on bounded cohomology". Riemann
   surfaces and related topics: Proceedings of the 1978 Stony Brook
   Conference (State Univ. New York, Stony Brook, N.Y., 1978), pp.
   53–63, Ann. of Math. Stud., 97, Princeton Univ. Press, Princeton,
   N.J., 1981.
2. Brooks, Robert; Series, Caroline. "Bounded cohomology for surface
       groups". Topology 23 (1984), no. 1, 29–36.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is that you first read some introductory texts on bounded cohomology (before trying to read Gromov's paper), here is just a small sample: [1](http://www.math.ethz.ch/u/burger/owr-burger.pdf)‎, 
[2](http://www.dm.unipi.it/~frigerio/files/note4.pdf), [3](http://www.math.kth.se/~skjelnes/SmallCoursesS08/Lect_MichelleIV.pdf), [4](http://people.uleth.ca/~dave.morris/talks/bddcoho.pdf).